# IncompatibleClassChangeError - Uprade to Spring 4.1.7

Tags: spring

We have a tomcat application that has a spring container running on 3.0.0. Upgraded to spring 4.1.7, and modified certain classes appropriately. One of the beans that we modified used CronTriggerBean. That was changed to use CronTriggerFactoryBean, and also upgraded to org.quartz-scheduler to 2.2.1. When deploying and starting tomcat, encountered the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean    
with name 'appsecScheduler' defined in class path resource [application-  
context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class at  
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean
```

Attached a debugger and found the offending class to be CronTriggerFactoryBean. But this issue happens only when deploying in a Windows environment. WHen the same war is deployed in Ubuntu, the application starts without any errors. For the record, I did a dependency:tree, dependency:build-classpath and ensured that 3.0.0 spring was not in use. The CronTriggerFactoryBean is part of spring-context-support. 
Any suggestions on how to debug further or determine which jar is being used?

Comment: You probably have the old version of the jar somewhere on the Windows machine and it ends up in the classpath, maybe in Tomcat's lib folder?

Comment: I had checked for jars under the tomcat/lib, but there were no spring-context-support jar, or the quartz jar that this class is part of.